# How do you solve this circular system of equations in $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to solve a system of equations in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ that look like this:

\begin{align}
x_1 + x_2 = p_1 \\
x_2 + x_3 = p_2 \\
x_3 + x_4 = p_3 \\
... \\
x_n + x_1 = p_n \\
\end{align}

I know that it can be represented as a matrix of size $n$ like this:

\begin{matrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & & 0 & 0\\
& & \vdots & & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}

and that this matrix is reducible in $\mathbb{R}$ when $n$ is odd. But I can't find a way to reduce it in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ because the inversion matrix in $\mathbb{R}$ involves $1/2$ and $1$ can't be divided by $2$ in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ because that would be division by zero.

Is this system solvable? Or if there are multiple solutions, is there some methodical way of figuring out what they are?

Comment: One quick note: add all the equations; if $p_1 + \cdots + p_n \neq 0$ then your system has no solution.

Comment: @AlexM. Yes, you're right.  I misread.

Comment: @Dr.MV: for $n=2$, there can be at most $2$ solutions.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: In fact, there are $4$, as I explain below. The "free parameters" of the system are taken to be $p_2$ and $x_2$, and this fixes the remaining ones. Since each of the free parameters can take $2$ values, this gives a total of $4$ solutions.

Comment: @AlexM.: no, there are two. As Dr.MV said, when $n=2$ the system is $x_1+x_2=p_1$. If $p_1=0$, the two solutions are $1,1$ and $0,0$. If $p_1=1$, the two solutions are $1,0$ and $0,1$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Indeed, I was thinking of something else (mistaken).

Answer (score 1):

The general matrix is given by the sum between the identity matrix and a circulant matrix, hence its characteristic polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$ is given by:
$$ p(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^n-1.$$
Over $\mathbb{F}_2$ such a matrix cannot be invertible since the sum of the elements in every row/column is zero, hence $(1,1,\ldots,1)$ is an eigenvector associated with the zero eigenvalue. To solve the system, you may just assume $x_1=0$ or $x_1=1$: after that, every value of $x_i$ is forced, and you get no contradiction unless $\sum p_j=1$.

Answer (score 0):

In $\mathbb{Z}_2$ the system matrix has determinant $0$, which means that the solution cannot be unique. Therefore, let us look at only the first $n-1$ equations, with $x_n$ considered not as an unknown, but as a parameter:then you solve the system backwards and get the solution $x_1 = p_n + x_n$ (remeber that in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ $+$ and $-$ coincide), $x_2 = p_1 + x_1 = p_1 + p_n + x_n$, $x_3 = p_2 + x_2 = p_1 + p_2 + p_n + x_n$ etc. up to $x_{n-1} = p_1 + p_2 + \cdots + p_{n-1} + p_n + x_n$.

But, as I've said in the comment above, in order for the system to have *any* solution it is necessary that $p_1 + \cdots + p_n = 0$, which shows that $x_{n-1} = x_n$. In turn, this means $p_{n-1} = 0$. In turn, this means that $x_{n-2} = x_n$, and so on up to $x_2 = x_n$ and $p_2 = 0$. Finally, you get $x_1 = p_1 +x_2 = p_n + x_n$. Calling $p=p_n$ and $x=x_n$, you get the solution $x_1 = p+x, x_2=x, x_3=x, \dots, x_{n-1}=x, x_n=x$. Since $x$ can be only $0$ or $1$, you get the following explicit solutions: $(p,0,\cdots,0), (p+1,1,\cdots,1)$.